# Change event not firing

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have cloned a table (with selects) to copy to somewhere else. This works great and I manage to change the ID's with no worries. The problem is that if I try to bind a change event to each of them, will it never fire? Is there a obvious mistake here? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var variants = $("table.variantselection").clone(false);

                variants.find("select").each(function (i, o) {
                    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_popup");
                });

                variants.find("select").change(function () {
                    alert($(this).val()); // never reaches this alert
                });

                variants.appendTo("#popup_variants");               
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change false to true to copy the event handlers with the DOM element

```
var variants = $("table.variantselection").clone(true);
```

Failing that, use the live() event to bind:

```
variants.find("select").live("change", function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Holy smokes - this works! I have been bugging with live aswell, but no idea why it works now. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Is there anyway I can preserve the user select value of the select field for the copy?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the `.change()` function *after* you've reattached the clone to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that `#popup_variants` is the parent element on your table, you might be better off to use `.delegate()`

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#popup_variants").delegate("select", "change", function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});

var variants = $("table.variantselection").clone(false);

variants.find("select").each(function(i, o) {
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_popup");
});

variants.appendTo("#popup_variants");
```

});